# What exactly does CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE mean

Tags: opencl

I am trying to understand what the constant `CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` means from an OpenCL device.

[This page](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) says that "Max number of pixels for a 1D image created from a buffer object.".

The value on my device is 2^24. However if I make an image from a buffer larger than 2^21 elements (channel_type is float, channel_order is R), reads become garbage-y.

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says.

The value returned is implementation dependent, but in general it will look like this:
Say you have `X` bytes as the maximum amount of system memory that you can allocate for a mem object. And say `Y` is the maximum value of bytes per pixel supported (This again depends on which all formats are supported). Then the value of the constant will in general be `X/Y` or lesser.
For example, if your image format is `CL_RGBA` and `CL_UNSIGNED_INT32`, then the bytes per pixel is 16

Assuming you meant the image pixels are garbage when you said "reads become garbage", it is definitely not caused because of this constant. You seem to be within limits. Are you sure that the parent buffer has stored float pixels in `CL_R` channel order?

Comment: If I create an image from a buffer that is smaller than 2^21 elements, than I can read values from the image no problem. If I create an image larger than 2^21 using the same code path, then reads return either 0s or garbage.

Comment: Can you please give me more details.. 1. What is CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE? 2. What is the image_desc value you sepcify when using clCreateImage 3. OCL device you are running this on?